# C# - Create vertical bar graph based on user input

Tags: c#

So I have started this out using a class that takes the input of data and stores it in an int. Then I use another public void to store that data in an array, and my thought process is to somehow find the max so that I can print it correctly in a vertical manner. However I am a beginner, and I am dumbfounded on how to start the printing.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
public class BarChart
{
   public int data1;
   public int data2;
   public int data3;
   public int data4;
   public int min;
   public int max;
   public void storeData()
   {
      int user1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      int user2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      int user3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      int user4 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      data1 = user1;
      data2 = user2;
      data3 = user3;
      data4 = user4;
   }
   public void displayGraph()
   {
      int[] data = new int[3];
      data[0] = data1;
      data[1] = data2;
      data[3] = data3;
      data[4] = data4;
      for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
      {
         if (max < data[i])
            max = data[i];
      }
      for (int j = 0; j < data.Length; j++)
      {
         if (min < data[j])
            min = data[j];
      }

   }


}
```

Comment: Where do you want to print? Into the console (using characters to represent your chart) or to a window or to a printer? These all require different code to perform the rendering.